# Using sf to combine polygons that share border with a polygon, but dropping the central polygon?

Tags: r, sf

I have rows of respondents within census polygons and am trying to generate first-order aggregated polygons, excluding the census unit a respondent resides in. Put another way, I want to combine neighboring polygons but exclude the polygon that touches all its neighbors.

st_union has been helpful in combining a polygon with its neighbors, but my trouble now is with dropping the central polygon.

I hope to remain within the sf environment.

Comment: Why are you including the "central polygon" in the union in the first place? Get the neighbour polygons and union that set, which won't include the "central polygon".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the DE9-IM relationship (see `st_relate` help page), and the function `st_filter` providing the relationship pattern, which in this case would be "FF2F11212":

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

df = read_sf("boundaries.gpkg")

# let's select a feature from the set, with []

df %>% st_filter(.,df[9,], .predicate = st_touches) %>%
  plot()
```

As you may see, the feature is not included in the plot
[image]

Comment: If you want to include polygons that touch at a single point, you can use `st_touches` for this instead of having to use st_relate with a DE9-IM string. Actually we don't know how the OP has computed adjacency...

Comment: `st_touches` was returning the central polygon also, OP says they should be dropped; maybe he could use `st_difference` after the union, but that would more slower

Comment: I can't replicate that: `example(st_read); st_touches(nc$geom[5], nc$geom)` doesn't show geometry 5 touching geometry 5, only 6, 9, 16 and 28.

Comment: you are right, I think I inadvertently wrote `st_intersects` at first attempt, so I went for the DEM9-IM, I'll edit the answer, thanks

Comment: @ElioDiaz This is very helpful; the st_filter predicate st_touches (or st_intersects) is absolutely what I need to obtain the neighbors list. My trouble now is with efficiently using st_union to combine the listed neighbors for each polygon ID. Any further assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you finding any trouble performing the union?

Comment: @ElioDiaz yes, because I'm not sure how to translate the resulting plotted area (or neighbors list) back into a sfc polygon. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you paste the code you've written so far?